# ¿como hacer tabla de 3 columnas para web de resultado de lotería que se vea bien en movil?

Tags: html

soy profano en esto del html, pero necesitaría algo fácil para hacer una tabla de los premios para mi web [comprobar loteria](http://www.comprobarloteria.net) es una página de resultados de lotería, resulta que tengo, por ejemplo, en la primitiva, tres columnas hechas con la etiqueta table, en una van las categorías (determinan las 6 filas), al lado el número de acertantes y en la 3ª columna el premio correspondiente. En el ordenador se ve bien, pero cuando sale en el móvil, me "descojona" la página y no se que solución darle al tema. Si alguien es tan amable de decirme una solución fácil para este tema lo agradezco

Comment: Hola Miguel, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Deberías hacer algunas mejoras a tu pregunta para que sea más fácil ayudarte: incluye el código de tu tabla, añade imágenes de cómo se ve mal y explica cuál era el resultado que esperabas obtener, evita vocabulario que pudiera ser malinterpretado. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y con ello ganar tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando si quieres una ayuda rapida y exacta debes mostrar parte de lo que intentas hacer. A pesar de que tu pregunta esta algo abstrapta voy a tratar de interpretar lo que has dicho.

Tienes una tabla en tu web que se visualiza bien en la PC pero cuando cambias a una resolucion menor (entiendase la de un movil, se distorciona).

Al parecer no estas utilizando estilos "responsive". Para eso no tienes que ser un experto. Existe herramientas como los mediaQuerys que te ayuda. Pero si quieres algo que te haga el trabajo bien facil y sin mucho esfuerzo. Utiliza [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Categorías de La Primitiva</th>
      <th scope="col">Nº de acertantes</th>
      <th scope="col">Premio Unitario</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1ª </th>
      <td>(6 Aciertos)</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0,00 €</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2ª</th>
      <td>(5 Aciertos + C)</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>247.228,36 €</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3ª</th>
      <td>(5 Aciertos)</td>
      <td>193</td>
      <td>2.775,45 €</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```